# jcifs with GWT: unsupported protocol smb

Tags: gwt, jcifs

So I'm writing a web app with GWT and GXT. I'm trying to use `jcifs.jar` to access files on a samba server and I keep getting an `"unsupported protocol"` message.

This is my code:

```
FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject buildLog = 
    manager.resolveFile("smb://tarzan/tgrid/build/build_log.txt");
InputStream stream = buildLog.getContent().getInputStream;
```

I read about this issue and I understand I need to add `jcifs.jar` to the GWT containers classpath, is that correct? And if so, what does it mean? How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're coding your client-side, and possibly RPC, with GWT is unrelated to the libraries you use on the server-side. Those libraries have to be in your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` folder. It's the same with the GWT DevMode, which simply embeds a lightweight HTTP server and servlet container.

Comment: thats what i did. i placed the jar under war/WEB_INF/lib and i get this message...am i missing something? where exactly should i place the jar and is there some more configuration needed?